# jquery lazyload images and webp with fallback

Tags: performance, lazy-loading, webp, jquery-lazyload

I am a bit confused how to use the picture fallback solution in combination with jquery lazyload. I use this library:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>
```

At the moment my images are integrated like this:

```
<img class="center lazy" data-original="./bilder/uebersetzung-marketing-bwl.png" width="593>
```

But webp fallback solution is structured like this:

```
<picture>
      <source class="center lazy" srcset="./bilder/Uebersetzungsdienst-Jena-BM-Translations.webp" type="image/webp">
      <img class="center lazy" src="./bilder/Uebersetzungsdienst-Jena-BM-Translations.png" width="1920" height="97" alt="Uebersetzungsdienst-Jena-BM-Translations">
</picture>
```

**My question:**
the integrated lazyload looks for `data-original` so it does not work with srcset. Is there a solution for that?

If possible I would prefer to do not use another library but "simply" add some code.

Comment: Do you meen adding imgWindowwidth refDesktop center to srouce?

Comment: Ive edited my question, hope its more clear now?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution.It is required to add data in specific format with custom attribute.
this code work perfectly and help for page optimization you add web or other format images.

**Note**: All format images with same name like,

- image_1.png
- image_1.jpg
- image_1.webp

Just change extension not name

```
<!-- Add this for show image  -->
<div class="lazy" data-name="image path1 without extension |image default extension (.png)|image alt tag|image classes"></div>
<div class="lazy" data-name="image path2 without extension |image default extension (.png)|image alt tag|image classes"></div>
<div class="lazy" data-name="image path3 without extension |image default extension (.png)|image alt tag|image classes"></div>

<!-- Add scripts in bottom  -->
<script>
function lazy_load(){
    $('.lazy').each(function(img){
        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
        var this_offset=$(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var window_offset=$(window).scrollTop()+ $(window).height();
        if($(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() <= ($(window).scrollTop()+ $(window).height())){
            var path_src=$(this).attr('data-name');
            var split_data=path_src.split('|');
            var img_html='<picture>'+
                '<source srcset="'+split_data[0]+'.webp" type="image/webp">'+
                '<source srcset="'+split_data[0]+split_data[1]+'" type="image/'+split_data[1].replace('.','')+'">'+
                '<img src="'+split_data[0]+split_data[1]+'" alt="'+split_data[2]+'" class="'+split_data[3]+'">'+
                '</picture>';
            $(this).html(img_html);
            $(this).show(1000);
            $(this).removeClass('lazy');
        }
    });
}
$(window).on('resize scroll', function(){
    lazy_load();
});
</script>
```

Lazy loading is now working perfectly.